# Best way to code a small Java 3d vector class

Tags: java, math, vector

Hi I am currently working on a little project and I have to add a class which allows me to add 2 vectors together / subtract them. 
The Vector for example  is Vector ( x,y,z )

What is the best way to code it? I do not want to use a class from the internet because I think the functionality I need is really basic.

Here some Pseudo Code I was thinking about:
The Vector (x,y,z) is a array with [0] = x, [1]=y [2]=z
So If we have Vector1(x1,y1,z1) and Vector 2(x2,y2,z2), we simply have a 3d array which basically contains [0]=x1+x2 [1]=y1+y2 and [2]=z1+z2
Is that the right way to go?

Comment: For this to be a good question, you should give us a suggestion of how **you** think you should do it, for example.

Comment: Write this kind of class in Java is horrible: Java generics sucks, and has no operator overloading. Even if you use the java way (no operators, "add" method and colleagues), the only way to transfer functionality in Java is through interfaces, making impossible to add two ints, for example.

Comment: [Look here for basic programming on custom classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: Here is what I was thinking about: Creating a Array for the vectors? Is this the right way to go?

Comment: @user3084311 As opposed to?

Comment: @user3084311 write up your ideas preferably in the post body. Make up some pseudocode if you think it makes your idea more clear.

Comment: I did! Would be happy for some feedback, I am kind of new to Java

Comment: Looks good to me. Once you start coding it your questions will become more clear, I think you just need to start.

Answer (score 3):

If your vectors are always in 3 dimensions, I would not go with an array, it will probably make things less clear. Try something like this:

```
public class Vector {
  private final double x;
  private final double y;
  private final double z;

  public Vector(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  // Getters...

  public Vector add(Vector addend) {
    return new Vector(x + addend.x, y + addend.y, z + addend.z);
  }

  // Other operations...
}
```

It's generally better to make the fields `final`, so you're certain your data does not surprisingly change value because you accidentally shared a reference with another part of the code.

Comment: Creating new objects is just a waste. There's no need to make them final if they're well encapsulated.

Comment: I disagree. Encapsulation does not prevent you from having two references to the same `Vector` instance in different parts of the code, and changing one will lead to a surprising change to the other. I would start with this approach, and go with mutability only in case of *proven* performance problems.

Comment: Using a vector class usually means a lot of vector calculations **e.g** a game. For example if there's 120 calculations per frame, 60 frames per second then there's 7200 new instances per second which is costly. Another reason why this is a bad idea is because it doesn't allow for method chaining, which is extremely useful for vector operations in java. vector.add(4, 3, 6).divide(2).sub(4, 2, 9) would become vector.add(4, 3, 6); vector.divide(2); vector.sub(4, 2, 9).

Comment: This does allow for method chaining. Regarding the cost, I don's say it's less costly: I say depending on the context, the extra cost might be negligible, and you gain in clarity, ease of use, less bugs.

Comment: Except for a game (where GC cost actually matters) immutability is preferred. «Effective Java 2nd ed.» is a good read on this topic.

Comment: @Darkhogg Why all Java people always abuses of encapsulation, and uses it even in cases where it's meaningless? Why do you need to encapsulate vector coordinates?

Comment: @Manu343726 You don't *need* it, it's usually done for uniformity. Everyone expects fields to be private and get<Whatever> methods to access those fields. As fields are `final`, accessing them directly would make no difference (and JITs will inline getter calls anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Just store each component as a variable. There's no need to use arrays. I'll just write something simple:

```
public class Vector3 {

    double x, y, z; // package-private variables; nice encapsulation if you place this in a maths package of something

    Vector3(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public Vector3 add(Vector3 vector) {
        x += vector.x;
        y += vector.y;
        z += vector.z;
        return this; // method chaining would be very useful
    }

}
```

Comment: In general, it's more beneficial to code these kind of classes which arebasic building blocks as *immutable classes*.

Comment: @Darkhogg The single source of performance optimization in my experience is to have mutable classes so that I can remove allocation by keeping around temporary classes that I use ovar again every frame.

Comment: @LennartRolland If it's for a game where you need to actively prevent the GC to run as much as possible, then yes, that's an optimization that I would also do. However, *in general*, it's not as beneficial as you think: allocation in Java is almost instant, the performance penalty only comes from GC, which is REALLY fast for short-lived objects an won't be noticed in most applications that doesn't require (near-)realtime performance.